# Undoing "Set as Start Page"

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-2

I set one of my ASP.net pages to the default start page in Visual Studio. This results in a 404 error when I try to debug my project. How do I clear this?

Thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Right click the MVC project and select properties.

Go to the Web tab.

Under Start Action, select either Current Page or Don't open a page.