# View as start page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3

I don't know about ASP.Net at all, I right click on the file Index.cshtml in views and accidentally choose "Set As Start Page"
Now when I run the application (Ctrl+F5), the error occurs

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.      
Requested URL: /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
```

Comment: Just set the original page back to be the start page.

Comment: Right click on the html/aspx file you want to be the start page and select "Set as Start Page" again.

Comment: @ChrisF - won't work, because no view is supposed to be a start page in an MVC project. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464070/undoing-set-as-start-page - or at least that has the solution.

Comment: Thanks, he self-voted. Bhuhhahhahaha

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio ASP.Net MVC undo set as start page action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821796/visual-studio-asp-net-mvc-undo-set-as-start-page-action)

Comment: Just added a VS tag, since it's really as much a "problem" with Visual Studio as with ASP.NET MVC. In most MVC projects "Set as Start Page" is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the settings in the Project properties, this other stack article should help:  [Visual Studio ASP.Net MVC undo set as start page action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821796/visual-studio-asp-net-mvc-undo-set-as-start-page-action)